# GridView Column.Count is always 0 after databind with a datatable

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I am trying to show/hide GridView columns conditionally.

I am creating a dynamic DataTable and then Binding it to the GridView

Later, on a post back, I am checking condition and want to show/hide a few columns of the GridView, but Column.Count is alway 0!

The code I have is as below -
ASPX page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

.CS Page

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable aDT = new DataTable()
   aDT = createDataTable();   //datatable has 21 columns

   GridView1.DataSource = aDT;
   GridView1.DataBind();

   int temp = GridView1.Columns.Count;   //always 0
}
```

Not sure what is wrong with the code

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can't access a column with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`, but you can access all cells via `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text` etc.

Comment: As I said, if the only thing for you to get count of columns, you can get it like that: `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: if the only thing he wants is the column-count he should not count the row's cells because it's possible that there are no rows at all which would cause an exception. Instead he should use  `aDT.Columns.Count`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, that's true. But, I thought that he may want to get count of columns in outside of the Button_Click method. And he can check if GridView contains any row.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: but if the grid contains no rows he can't get the column count from the first row's cell-count. So a check does not help. But `aDT.Columns.Count` works always.

Answer (score 9):

If you set the `autogeneratedcolumns` property to `true`  then the count will always show 0.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx)

> The Columns property (collection) is used to store all the explicitly
>   declared column fields that get rendered in the GridView control. You
>   can also use the Columns collection to programmatically manage the
>   collection of column fields.

In your case, you didn't declared your columns explicitly. So you can get columns count like this inside and outside of the Click method if GridView contains at least one row:

> Cells Count in a Row = Columns Count.

```
if(GridView1.Rows.Count>0)
    int temp = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
```

Or you can get counts from DataTable inside Click method like that as @[TimSchmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) commented:

```
int temp = aDT.Columns.Count
```

Comment: But you won't get the column count if the grid contains no rows. Use the `DataTable.Columns.Count` property instead which works always.

Comment: How can I still get the number of columns if I have the autogeneratedcolumns property to false?  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

[`GridView.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) returns a [`DataControlFieldCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.aspx).

From it's remarks-section:

> If you are using the `GridView` or `DetailsView` control, the
>   `DataControlField` objects that are automatically created (for example,
>   when the **`AutoGenerateColumns`** property is `true`) **are not stored** in the
>   publicly accessible fields collection. You can only access and
>   manipulate DataControlField objects that are not automatically
>   generated.

From the [`GridView.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) remarks section:

> Explicitly declared column fields can be used in combination with
>   automatically generated column fields. When both are used, explicitly
>   declared column fields are rendered first, followed by the
>   automatically generated column fields. **Automatically generated column
>   fields are not added to the Columns collection**.

So only columns added declaratively are accessible in `GridView.Columns`. Since you have set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true` (default) they are not added to the `Columns` collection.

If you need the column count you should use your `DataSource`. The `DataTable` has a [`Columns` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) which is initialized even if the table does not contain rows:

```
int temp = aDT.Columns.Count;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time, what is the alternative way of getting the Column names?

Comment: @user1889838: `DT.Columns.Count`, the `DataTable`'s columns are set even if doesn't contain rows (as opposed to `GridView.Rows[0].Cells. Count`). Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Change these in ASPX page:**

1. Set the autogeneratecolumns="false".
2. Add `<columns>` tags as below:

> ```
>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server">
>     <columns>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="Postal Code"/>
>         <asp:boundfield datafield="Country" headertext="Country"/>
>      </columns>
>  </asp:GridView>
> ```

**In .CS file:**

int temp = GridView1.Columns.Count;   // will return 6