# Making gridview column invisible after binding - Index out of range exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, indexoutofrangeexception

I am binding data to gridview in a button click event. After binding data, I am checking if the user is Admin or not. If the user is not admin, I want to make some columns not visible. But it is throwing the 'Index out of range exception'. Below is my code.

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridStaffBindData();

        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand checkAdminCmd = new SqlCommand("query", sqlCon);
        object admin = checkAdminCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if(admin == null)
        {
          gridStaff.Columns[0].Visible = false; //throwing exception here
        } 
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

I am guessing. tt must be something simple that I am missing here.

My GridStaffBind function is very simple. I dont think there is a prob in that. Anyway, below is the code.

```
    private void GridStaffBindData()
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        string sqlCommand = "select command";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, sqlCon);
        da.Fill(dt);

        sqlCon.Close();

        gridStaff.DataSource = dt;
        gridStaff.DataBind();
    }
```

The data is perfectly binding to the gridview when I commented that exception line of code. So, I think there is no fault with the data.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for GridStaffBindData()? It looks like gridStaff hasn't been filled and therefore there is no column at index 0, hence the exception.

Comment: Hi, updated my code with GridStaffBindData functionality

Comment: Have you checked that dt contains data? If this is empty then gridStaff will also be empty and therefore not have a column at index 0.

Comment: Also, exactly what do you think string slqCommand = "select command"; is doing?

Comment: Something strange is happening here. I commented the problem line of code and started debugging. 'dt' has no data. Then i took the query and executed in SSMS and it showed some data there. and I pressed F5 to see the final result and the gridview has data bound to it. whats happening?? argh

Comment: You took the query "select command" and it showed data? Really??? What is the query you executed in SSMS?

Comment: SELECT Name, Phone, Email, Department, Directorate FROM MyTable WHERE Date='2014-03-17' AND location='LONDON' AND Time='AM'

Comment: Then that's the what you need to put into string sqlCommand, not the words "select command".

Comment: ok, I restarted my visual studio and now i have data in dt(only Microsoft knows the reason). After binding it to the gridview, i am trying to get gridview.columns.count. it is showing as '0'

Comment: I just put the "select command" bacause I did not want to reveal my actual command here :p . My actual code has the real command.

Comment: hi sr28, finally found it. I have to set AutoGenrateColumns="false" to get the columns count or to perform any operations on grid columns. Thanks for your support

Comment: If you're creating you're own columns then yes. If you simply want to fill a gridview then don't specify any columns and just set AutoGenerateColumns to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it.

If the gridview autogeneratecolumns="true", then the gridview columns count is always zero. So, I set that to false and defined all columns as asp:Boundfields.

[GridView Column.Count is always 0 after databind with a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613818/gridview-column-count-is-always-0-after-databind-with-a-datatable)

Thanks for your contribution guys

Answer (score 0):

You should check column count before using it to avoid 'Index out of range exception' like this

```
   if(admin == null && gridStaff.Columns.Count>0)
    {
      gridStaff.Columns[0].Visible = false; //throwing exception here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi what are you doing in the GridStaffBindData(); function 
maybe your datasource remains empty and then you get exception.