# Make auto generated column readonly in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.6

I have a `DataGridView` whose `DataSource` is a `DataTable` with five columns. If I attempt to access a column's `ReadOnly` property, like so:

```
datagridview.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
```

It throws a `NullReferenceExcpetion`.

I understand this is due to how the framework manages its auto generated columns, as noted by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613818/gridview-column-count-is-always-0-after-databind-with-a-datatable).

My question is: How do I make a column(s) readonly when the data source is auto generated?

Comment: did you try using the `DataBindingComplete` event? I'm almost sure when that event is fired, you already have access to all autogenerated columns... give it  try. Just open the EVents panel and double click on the event, then debug and check the columns.

Comment: @balexandre Yes, that works, too! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really say why it's not working, but a simple test with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GenerateData();

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private List<DataSourceTest> GenerateData()
    {
        return new List<DataSourceTest>()
        {
            new DataSourceTest(1, "A"),
            new DataSourceTest(2, "B"),
            new DataSourceTest(3, "C"),
            new DataSourceTest(4, "D"),
            new DataSourceTest(5, "E"),
            new DataSourceTest(6, "F"),
        };
    }
}

public class DataSourceTest
{
    public DataSourceTest(int id, string name) { ID = id; Name = name; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and making the gridview `EditMode` set to `EditOnEnter` so we can easily check if it's readonly or not, shows that it does the job well.

**But if you still have issues**, the best bet is to use an event, and the closest event for your question is the `DataBindingComplete` that will fire after the binding is done, so on that time, you will have full access to all your columns as they already bind to the gridview object.

double click on the event in the GridView control and add your readonly setter:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(
    object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: It's a head scratcher, but the use of the `DataBindingComplete` event worked for me. Obviously I have some property flag enabled somewhere along the way which is causing me issues. However, between this and my answer, my problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make column read-only when column has been generated

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Student> allStudent = new List<Student>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            allStudent.Add(new Student { Name = "Student" + i, Roll = i + 1 });
        }

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = allStudent;

        //Edited to show column count
        MessageBox.Show("Column count is " + dataGridView1.Columns.Count);

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            column.ReadOnly = true;
        }

    }

    public partial class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Roll { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As it uses `AutoGeneratedColumns`, the column count will always return 0, meaning that loop's content will never execute. Inspect `datagridview.Columns.Count`. Thank for for your answer, though.

Comment: @Momit Column count is returning 0. Sorry, don't know what to say.

Comment: @TEK .. is it showing 0 still there(where i put messagebox) .. but that is not possible ..until `allStudent` variable is `null` ..  my example showing it `2`

Comment: I think it's a problem on my end with the DataGridView, I may have inadvertently toggled a property. :)

Answer (score 0):

In true TEK fashion, I figured out a solution to my own question:

To do this, you need to make use of the `ColumnAdded` event

```
datagridview.ColumnAdded += dataGridView_ColumnAdded;
```

Then in the event, you can check a column by name:

```
  private void dataGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
  {
        if (e.Column is DataGridViewColumn)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn column = e.Column as DataGridViewColumn;
            column.ReadOnly = true;
            if (column.Name == "first_name")
            {
                column.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
  }
```